# How to fix EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/.... when installing gatsby-cli

Tags: terminal, static, frontend, backend, gatsby

I'm setting up Gatsby and get stuck at the beginning.
When i write npx/npm install global gatsby-cli in the terminal -
Alems-MacBook-Pro:~ alemkahrobek$ npm install -g gatsby-cli i see this:

/usr/local/bin/gatsby -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js

> gatsby-telemetry@1.0.4 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
> node src/postinstall.js

- gatsby-cli@2.5.4
  added 225 packages from 131 contributors in 13.617s.

If i check the version of gatsby i get this:

```
Alems-MacBook-Pro:~ alemkahrobek$ gatsby -v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:49
            throw error;
            ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/alemkahrobek/.config/gatsby/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:344:35)
    at Configstore.get all [as all] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:31:25)
    at new Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:25:48)
    at new Store (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/store.js:28:51)
    at new EventStorage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/event-storage.js:24:50)
    at new AnalyticsTracker (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/telemetry.js:32:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/index.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10).
```

Now if i try to make a new project like:

```
gatsby new example
```

i get this:

```
Alems-MacBook-Pro:~ alemkahrobek$ npm gatsby new example


Usage: npm <command>


where <command> is one of:

access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,

clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,

create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,

edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,

install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,

login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,

profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,

run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,

stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,

uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,

whoami


npm <command> -h quick help on <command>

npm -l display full usage info

npm help <term> search for help on <term>

npm help npm involved overview


Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:

/Users/alemkahrobek/.npmrc

or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value

Config info can be viewed via: npm help config



npm@6.9.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm


Alems-MacBook-Pro:~ alemkahrobek$ npm help config


NPM-CONFIG(1) NPM-CONFIG(1)


NAME

npm-config - Manage the npm configuration files


SYNOPSIS

npm config set <key> <value> [-g|--global]

npm config get <key>

npm config delete <key>

npm config list [-l] [--json]

npm config edit

npm get <key>

npm set <key> <value> [-g|--global]


aliases: c


DESCRIPTION

npm gets its config settings from the command line, environment vari-

ables, npmrc files, and in some cases, the package.json file.


See npm help 5 npmrc for more information about the npmrc files.


See npm help 7 npm-config for a more thorough discussion of the mechanisms involved.

The npm config command can be used to update and edit the contents of

the user and global npmrc files.


Sub-commands

Config supports the following sub-commands:


set

npm config set key value


Sets the config key to the value.


If value is omitted, then it sets it to "true".


get

npm config get key


Echo the config value to stdout.


list

npm config list


Show all the config settings. Use -l to also show defaults. Use --json

to show the settings in json format.


delete

npm config delete key


Deletes the key from all configuration files.


edit

npm config edit


Opens the config file in an editor. Use the --global flag to edit the

global config.



SEE ALSO

o npm help 5 folders


o npm help 7 config


o npm help 5 package.json


o npm help 5 npmrc
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users who experience the same problem, I've solved it giving the right permissions on the specified folder:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/gatsby
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official page on npmjs.com: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

I would definitely the first option on that page. nvm is pretty awesome: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Thank you for the link. I went with the second option, manually changing the default directory, and it worked!